# AWS S3 - PreSigned Url file upload and download

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have functions for uploading and downloading files to aws s3 in backend. file download functionality is working but getting error with upload file url. The URL generates easily but cannot be opened.
showing error message such as
I tried changing content type and key
I want the url to be opened and let me upload file from my local storage.

getting error as shown in above picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpgtp.png)

Comment: Error clearly saying that the signature for your PreSigned Url is not valid.

Comment: How did you generate the S3 pre-signed URL?

Answer (score 0):

There [are 2 versions of an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html) in the AWS Example Code Library that show creating a presigned URL for upload. And there is a related example in that repository that g[enerates a presigned URL and returns it from a Lambda](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/cross-services/photo-asset-manager/src/common.js) function (shown below). Both examples can be downloaded and run locally.

```
 **
 * Creates a presigned URL for uploading an object to Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3).
 * @param {{ bucket: string, key: string, contentType }} object - The object to create a presigned URL for.
 */
export const createPresignedPutURL = ({ bucket, key, contentType }) => {
  const client = new S3Client({});
  // Expires in 15 minutes.
  const expiresIn = 15 * 60;
  const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    ContentType: contentType,
  });
  return getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn });
};
```

Maybe one of those will help you?